# How to return an alternate column element from the intersect command?

Tags: python, intersection

I am currently using the following code to get the intersection date column 
of two sets of financial data. The arrays include date, o,h,l,cl

```
#find intersection of date strings
def intersect(seq1, seq2):
    res = []                     # start empty
    for x in seq1:               # scan seq1
        if x in seq2:            # common item?
            res.append(x)


    return res


x = intersect(seta[:,0], setb[:,0])    # mixed types
print x
```

The problem is it only returns the column for which it found the
intersection of both, namely the date column.
I would like it to somehow return a different column array
including both the cls values of each set ... ie..
if date is common to both return a 2X1 array of the two corresponding
cls columns.  Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "cls values" and "cls columns"?

Comment: Is *set[:,0]* a slice expression? I've never seen something like this before.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is a complete solution.

Get a [python library to download stocks quotes](http://www.goldb.org/ystockquote.html)

Get some quotes

```
start_date, end_date = '20090309', '20090720'
ibm_data = get_historical_prices('IBM', start_date, end_date)
msft_data = get_historical_prices('MSFT', start_date, end_date)
```

Convert rows into date-keyed dictionaries of dictionaries

```
def quote_series(series):
    columns = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
    return dict((item[0], dict(zip(columns, item[1:]))) for item in series[1:])

ibm = quote_series(ibm_data)
msft = quote_series(msft_data)
```

Do the intersection of dates thing

```
ibm_dates = set(ibm.keys())
msft_dates = set(msft.keys())

both = ibm_dates.intersection(msft_dates)

for d in sorted(both):
    print d, ibm[d], msft[d]
```

Comment: Hey Hugh, is this structure of *item* some financial data common place that everybody is familar with?!

Comment: You've modelled each data item as an object, but if I got the OP right, each is an array. So your set constructors should probably go *set(item[0]...)*, your dicts like *dict((item[0], item[1:])...)* and your print statement *print d, da[d][3], db[d][3]*, since OP is only interested in the cl part of each item, right?!

Answer (score 0):

How's that:

```
def intersect(seq1, seq2):
    if seq1[0] == seq2[0]:  # compare the date columns
        return (seq1[4], seq2[4])  # return 2-tuple with the cls values
```